Why is this indexing the array?
In the Wikipedia article for "Undefined behaviour", there is a section showing that this is undefined behaviour in C/C++:
int arr[4] = { 0, 1, 2, 3 };
int* p = arr + 5;  // undefined behavior for indexing out of bounds
p = NULL;
int a = *p;        // undefined behavior for dereferencing a null pointer

When you do int* p = arr + 5; you're incrementing the value of the pointer by 5 * sizeof(int), but there's no dereferencing done, and no indexing of the array, so why is this undefined behaviour according to this?

It's undefined behavior just to create a pointer outside the object, even if you don't dereference it.

@Barmar I seem to remember that creating a pointer exactly one behind array, i.e. arr+4 in this example, is allowed, as long as it is not dereferenced. Do you agree? (This does not contradict your previous comment, only adds precision.)

@Yunnosch yes, that's allowed. It allows you to use that as the limit in a loop, for example.

@Barmar, my understanding is that ending iterators point past the container, like one past, but this is not undefined behavior.  Dereferencing is undefined behavior.

@ThomasMatthews Right. You're allowed to write for (int *p = arr; p < arr+4; p++) { code that defererences p }

@Barmar So assigning a value to a pointer to memory isn't valid for you to dereference is UB, so int* p = 0xFF; is in itself UB, but int* p = 0x00; is OK because it's equivalent to NULL? And there's also the exception of exactly one byte past the end of valid memory?

@Zebrafish Exactly. I think int *p = 0xFF; may be implementation-defined, I haven't looked it up specifically. But your question is about pointer arithmetic, not about converting integer to pointer.

The compiler is allowed to put the array at the end of memory, so arr + 5 might not exist.

@BoP Right, but is that specifically because of integer overflow, or simply because the address isn't a valid address? Like, int *p = 0xABCD; that memory address might "not exist", as you put it.

@Zebrafish - We have seen architectures where the hardware verified pointers against memory segment sizes. Just loading an invalid pointer into an address register could trap. So the language allows that.

@Lundin: While this was my intuition also, it seems that is not actually the case :-(

@einpoklum As seen in the quote in the posted answer, doing pointer arithmetic exactly 1 item beyond the end of the array is well-defined behavior, as long as that item is not de-referenced.

Oh wait there's 4 items so arr + 4 is well-defined but arr + 5 is not. Ok so I did the classic off-by-one mistake as well :) Horrible example to use on a wikipedia site regardless.

@BoP: Even in cases where memory beyond the end of an array would be guaranteed to exist, e.g. becasue the array is nested within a larger array, gcc will interpret an attempt to read arr[0][i] as an invitation to assume that the program will never receive input that would cause i to exceed the bounds of the inner array, and behave in nonsensical ways that may arbitrarily corrupt memory if that assumption is invalid.

It is undefined behavior, as that term is used in the C standard, because the C standard does not define pointer arithmetic for this case. Below, I quote the entire paragraph in the C standard about this, but here is a simpler explanation. For adding an integer N to a pointer P, the standard says that if P points to A[i], where A[i] is either an element of the array or is what would one beyond the last element, then P+N is defined to point to A[i+N], as long as A[i+N] is also either an element of the array or is what would be one beyond the last element.
That means if A[i+N] would be anything else, the behavior is not defined, because there is no definition of what the result should be. But the standard goes further than just leaving a definition unstated; it explicitly states that if A[i+N] would be anything else, the behavior is not defined.
So, if you have int A[4];, then &A[2] + 2 is defined to point to just beyond the last element, but &A[2] + 3 is undefined.
You might think of address arithmetic in hardware terms. If you have the address of A[2] in hardware and add the number of bytes of 3 elements, you get the address where A[5] would be if A were bigger. But a C implementation is not obliged to work with hardware addresses when doing its pointer calculations. Conforming to the C standard only requires it to support the calculations defined by the standard.
Text of the C standard
C 2018 6.5.6 8 says:

When an expression that has integer type is added to or subtracted from a pointer, the result has the
type of the pointer operand. If the pointer operand points to an element of an array object, and the
array is large enough, the result points to an element offset from the original element such that the
difference of the subscripts of the resulting and original array elements equals the integer expression.
In other words, if the expression P points to the i-th element of an array object, the expressions
(P)+N (equivalently, N+(P)) and (P)-N (where N has the value n) point to, respectively, the i + n-th
and i − n-th elements of the array object, provided they exist. Moreover, if the expression P points to
the last element of an array object, the expression (P)+1 points one past the last element of the array
object, and if the expression Q points one past the last element of an array object, the expression
(Q)-1 points to the last element of the array object. If both the pointer operand and the result point
to elements of the same array object, or one past the last element of the array object, the evaluation
shall not produce an overflow; otherwise, the behavior is undefined. If the result points one past
the last element of the array object, it shall not be used as the operand of a unary * operator that is
evaluated.


So all the examples are talking about incrementing past an array, what about int x; int* p = &x + 2; ?  I assume &x + 1 is valid according to the {plus one} exception rule. But this isn't an array, it's just a single object/int

@Zebrafish: A nearby paragraph of the standard says that, for the purposes of defining pointer arithmetic, a single object is treated as an array of one element.

How about decrementing the pointer? I guess the {one-off exception} is handy there too as it's used when decrementing in loops, however decrementing past that? This is so weird, I've used C and C++ for so long and I don't know any of this.

@Zebrafish: The C standard does not define pointer arithmetic that would result in pointing to before the start of the array.

The inability to point before the start of an array or more than one past the end of an array was a conscious decision by the C committee. See Rationale section 6.5.6, page 68, lines 14-28.

Around the time that the C89 Standard was being written, some toolset vendors were devloping tools that could be configured to trap on out-of-bounds array accesses, even within a nested object.  Given e.g. char arr[5][3];, the tool may allow a programmer to indicate that a particular access to arr[0][i] should be treated as a faster shorthand for arr[i/3][i%3], but could also be configured to trap if i exceeded 2.
Because the C89 Standard had no way of exercising any jurisdiction whatsoever over corner cases that might trap on some implementations, other than forbidding trapping behavior, it characterized as UB any attempt to access arr[0][i] as UB, on the presumption that implementations would treat it as arr[i/3][i%3] in cases where their customers would require such treatment, whether or not the Standard mandated such behavior, and thus there was no need for a standard syntax to specify such treatment.
Note that gcc will interpret this provision as an invitation to assume that nothing the program might possibly do in response to inputs that would attempt to read arr[0][i] with i in the range 3 to 14 would be considered unacceptable, even though the behavior of the construct had been defined in the language the Standard was chartered to describe.

The question isn't about out-of-bounds access. It's about pointer arithmetic without dereferencing the pointer.

A compiler which displaced address arr[0] by i bytes when i is in the range 0 to 14 would, in the absence of UB, produce a pointer equal to arr[i/3]+(i%3); an access to the storage there would be an access to arr[i/3][i%3], which would be guaranteed to exist.  My point was that things aren't UB merely because the out-of-bounds addresses might not exist, because the existence of valid storage at the computed address doesn't preclude the possibility that compilers may behave nonsensically anyhow.

Your answer keeps saying "access" and "read", it never says anything about calculating the pointer value without accessing anything with it. But the standard says that merely calculating the pointer value is UB.

@Barmar: If an access to arr[1][2] would have defined behavior, and if displacing arr[0] by 5 bytes would yield a pointer equal to arr[1][2], that would suggest that if computation of arr[0]+5 were defined, accessing arr[0][5] would be equivalent to addressing arr[1][2].

I understand that. The question is why is it UB to just calculate the address, even if you never access the value there?

Note that you're not allowed to access the value 1 past the end of an array, but you are allowed to use array arithmetic to produce that pointer. So you can't say that you mustn't calculate any pointer that you can't dereference.

@Barmar: The one-past scenario complicates the analysis, to be sure, but if the possibility of accessing an invalid memory addrress wasn't the motivating factor for treating treating arr[0][i] as UB for i in the rang 3 to 14, but the possibility of implementations error-trapping out-of-bounds accesses was, it would seem likely that similar rationale would have applied for address computations.

They're definitely related. But your answer never explains that justification. The other answer already does, and you're complicating things by talking about 2-dimensional arrays.

@Barmar: My point with two-dimensional arrays is that there is no possibility that arr[0]+4 would attempt to compute an address beyond the end of accessable storage, becasue the first 15 bytes starting at the beginning of the array are guaranteed to be valid.
